# Liferay Calendar how to send mails to all members of a group id

Tags: email, notifications, calendar, liferay, hook

I work on a Liferay 6.2 project and I must hook the liferay calendar portlet. In normal mode the liferay calendar send an email notification to the creator of an event. I want to send a email for each member of a group. Send a notification email on each member.

I have hook the calendar with the following path :
/home/[...]/plugins/hooks/calendar-hook/docroot/custom-jsp/html/portlet/calendar/view.jsp
(I have other jsp files like days.jsp)

I know I have to override the liferay java class CalEventLocalServiceImp and define a new function remindUser(CalEvent event, User user, Calendar startDate)

with, for example, the following line :

```
protected void remindUser(CalEvent event, [...], Calendar startDate) {
[...]
    List<User> users = GroupUtil.getUsers(event.getGroupId());
    for(User user : users){
        [...]
        List<User> users = GroupUtil.getUsers(event.getGroupId());
        remindUser(event,user,startDate);
        [...]
    }
[...]
}
```

My problem is I don't know where the code call that function and where I am supposed to override it.
I don't see the link between the jsp and my java override class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can see, Liferay 6.2's calendar is contained in a plugin, not in core. This means that you can't override it with a hook, but will need to operate along the lines of a [plugin extending another plugin](https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/6-2/creating-plugins-to-extend-plugins). This means that you'll need to update a modified version of that plugin

Comment: So I have not to create a custom class that extends a wrapper and declare it in the "liferay-hook.xml" for signaled it will be replaced a service ?

Comment: After a verification I'm on liferay 6.1.1; not in 6.2

Comment: Please decide. You're opening your question with "I work on a Liferay 6.2 project". If you're indeed on 6.1.1: Upgrade. It's long out of service and doesn't get any updates, security- or stability-related since 2013